# Code Coverage for Integration tests using Jacoco

Tags: jacoco

I am passing `jacocoagent.jar` of version 0.8.1 as a java agent to record the code coverage on the server to my server start-up script. But I see that Pre-main class attribute is missing in the jar, as a result, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in 
/u01/jetty_home/jacoco/jacocoagent.jar
agent library failed to init: instrument.
```

Does anyone have thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you use proper JAR file.

`lib/jacocoagent.jar` in `jacoco-0.8.1.zip` that is linked from [JaCoCo homepage](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) has following checksums

```
$ wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco/0.8.1/jacoco-0.8.1.zip

$ unzip jacoco-0.8.1.zip

$ md5sum lib/jacocoagent.jar
2873d7006dc9672d84981792df2c5b7a  lib/jacocoagent.jar

$ sha256sum lib/jacocoagent.jar
cd40d1c1aea4112adb82049df3f462b60380ce1bb00bdecb1cfdb862e34be8dd  lib/jacocoagent.jar
```

JaCoCo homepage also contains link on [JaCoCo documentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/), which contains page ["Maven Repository"](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html) with explanation that exactly the same artifact in Maven Central Repository has groupId `org.jacoco`, artifactId `org.jacoco.agent` and most importantly **classifier `runtime`** :

> Following JAR files are available:
>
> ```
> Group ID   | Artifact ID      | Classifier | Description
> -----------+------------------+------------+-------------
> ...
> org.jacoco | org.jacoco.agent |            | API to get a local copy of the agent
> org.jacoco | org.jacoco.agent | runtime    | Agent
> ...
> ```

so its filename is [org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.1/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar)

```
$ wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.1/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar

$ md5sum org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar
2873d7006dc9672d84981792df2c5b7a  org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar

$ sha256sum org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar
cd40d1c1aea4112adb82049df3f462b60380ce1bb00bdecb1cfdb862e34be8dd  org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar
```

and both have `Premain-Class` attribute

```
$ unzip lib/jacocoagent.jar

$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Premain
Premain-Class: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer : it seems in v0.8.4 that only runtime jar has this attribute ...

Comment: @jy95 Please re-read carefully - in all versions up to 0.8.4: jar with artifactId `org.jacoco.agent` and classifier `runtime` is absolutely identical to `lib/jacocoagent.jar` from zip-distribution and so both have `Premain-Class` attribute, whereas jar without classifier never had and does not have this attribute, because it is not agent, but "API to get a local copy of the agent".

Comment: just extracted both jars and only found that attribute in the runtime jar :(

Comment: @jy95 once again:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco/0.8.4/jacoco-0.8.4.zip
contains
`lib/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4.201905082037.jar`
which is identical to
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.4/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4.jar
and both do not have `Premain-Class` because this is not agent, but "API to get a local copy of the agent"
Same zip contains agent at
`lib/jacocoagent.jar`
which is identical to
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.4/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar
and both have `Premain-Class`. Hope clear now.