# jacocoagent.jar starts up fails: agent library failed to init: instrument

Tags: jacoco

recently I'm learning jacocoagent,
I used the following command to start my project,

````
```nohup java -javaagent:/root/qa_charlyne/jacocoagent.jar=includes=*,output=file,destfile=/root/qa_charlyne/jacoco.exec -jar diff-code-coverage.jar > difflog.txt 2>&1```
````

but i failed to start up jacocoagent.jar:
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in /root/qa_charlyne/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

i don't know why ,i need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Coverage for Integration tests using Jacoco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644625/code-coverage-for-integration-tests-using-jacoco)

Answer (score 0):

The jacoco jar file without classifier from maven repo (ex. org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5.jar) is not the one that should be used as an agent.
Instead use the one with "runtime" classifier (ex. org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar).

Link to central maven repo: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.5/